# AirTable - how to get form data in an ensuing automation script

Tags: airtable

Here is my problem:

- I have a form that lets users enter some data.
- When the form is submitted, I want to fire off an http request to populate a remote DB
  using the data entered in that form.
- I have set up an automation script to run when the form is submitted.
- That call will result in a record being created in that database and a subsequent unique ID. I need to be able to make that call and the enter the record using that returned ID.
- I cannot figure out how to get the data from the form which is being submitted.

I have not worked with AirTable much and this is my first time using forms. I did not create the form in question. Whenever I have written automations or scripts in the past, I have used commands like the ones below to get the table and the record in question:

```
let table = base.getTable("Planning Database");
let thisRecord = await input.recordAsync("", table).catch();
```

I'm thinking that there must be a similar way to get data from the form that triggered the automation script being run? Something like ...

```
let formData = base.getForm("My Awesome Form");
```

Thanks